# Should short, simple functions be functions at all?

Tags: encapsulation

**Let's take a look at this JavaScript function:**

```
function setDivId(div, id) {
        div.id = id;
        return div;
    }
```

- Would I lose any performance by encapsulating something this short?
- Would I be better off writing *div.id = something;* in the right context as a one-liner?
- Is there any point of encapsulating a function, if the smaller,  lower-level functions (that make up the larger function) are unlikely to be used again?
- Should functions always be encapsulated? What's an example of when a function shouldn't be broken down (if it can be)?

Comment: This doesn't encapsulate anything. `setDivId` isn't any clearer, shorter, or more meaningful than assigning to `div.id` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I believe there is a misunderstanding of encapsulation. Encapsulation refers to the restricting of components (classes, variables, etc.) in an application. Here's a high-level example: a class named `ClassOne` would not be able to access a private variable in a class named `ClassTwo` because the variable has been marked private and only accessible by `ClassOne`. You can read more about encapsulation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28computer_programming%29).

What you are actually doing with that function is attempting to make it easier and more convenient for you, the programmer, to set a given `div`'s `id` attribute. Technically speaking, functions do impact performance, but in most compiled languages, the compiler uses [inlining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) to negate that performance impact. And you should not be concerned with the performance implications of creating a function since they are negligible. You should be asking yourself if the function is necessary, reduces redundancy, and speeds up development time.

To address your questions:

- No, the function will basically not impact performance.
- You are better off doing this because it's a simple, one-line assignment. By writing the function, you are not saving yourself any time or making your code more concise.
- Sometimes writing a function for the purposes of code clarity can be useful. But if the code in the function is only used once and is as short as the one in your question, then it does not make much sense to create a function. If a short function is a few lines longer than your example and is used multiple times within a larger function, then yes it would make sense to put the code in a function, even if it is not used anywhere other than that function. Why? It reduces code redundancy.
- Functions by the nature of the term do not belong to an object and are not encapsulated. Functions that belong to an object, which is often a `Class`, are called `methods`. Yes, you should encapsulate methods because they should only be accessible by the object they belong to.